Vlookup for items in a comma separated list
I have a table with different values associated with different name.



Column A
Column B




height 1
2


width 1
5


height 2
8


width 2
9



In another sheet, I have a table with multiple values separated by comma in each cell.



Column A1
Column B1




height1, width2
Sum???


width2, height 2
sum???



I would like to use Vlookup for each name separated by comma in Column A1 and get autosum for them in Column B1 using their values in Column B.
Please help.
I have multiple formulas but it doesn’t work

If you're on Windows, here's an example to try:

Use FILTERXML to split by ,
For VLOOKUP with exact matches (FALSE as the last parameter), we need to strip spaces in values - with SUBSTITUTE(…," ","")
Enter the formula in B8 and fill down as needed
-- is used to convert text numbers (result of SUBSTITUTE) to numbers

=SUM(--VLOOKUP(
FILTERXML("<x><h_w>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A8," ", ""), ",", "</h_w><h_w>") & "</h_w></x>", "//h_w"),
SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$B$5, " ",""), 2,FALSE))


